# Is there any referencing style analyzer?

Tags: publications, citations, reference-managers

As different journals and Conference proceedings have different reference styles, it is very much important to quickly identify the specific reference style they prefer.

To do this, is there any reference style analyzer which can analyze a given example reference style and give the name of the style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the name of the reference style is in general Journal X's style. Even journals that claim to stick to a standard style (e.g., APA, MLA, Chicago) often throw in little twists. In general I find that if you get close, journals are pretty forgiving and will copy edit you to the correct style.

Basically you want your in text citations to follow either an author-number (Vancouver) or author-date (Harvard) style. As for the list of citations, just make sure it has all the information that the journal uses (e.g., DOI if the journal uses it).

Answer (score 3):

Each journal will have a **guide for authors** that will specify the required reference style. That's the fastest, easiest and most reliable method.

Comment: Yes, but what about others who don't give specific name of the referencing style, rather giving some example reference? Right now I'm confused with this one - Chung, KT; Stevens, SE and Bultron, G. 1993. Degradation of azo dyes by environmental microorganism and helminthes. Environ. Toxicol. Chem., 12(2): 121-132.

Comment: Why not include that, and the name of the journal / conference in the question? If it really does have a publisher that can't be bothered to provide an adequate guide for authors, let's at least name and shame them.

Comment: @Md.GolamRashed The style looks like [Vancouver system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vancouver_system). The references are numbered.