# Tool that suggests references based on a given bibliography

Tags: citations, literature-search

I'd like to have a tool (software or website) that helps me in doing literature surveys. Here's how I pictured that tool in my mind.
Let's suppose that I've found myself a few relevant papers. As soon as I feed such references to the tool, it starts suggesting me other papers I might be interested to. Suggested references could be paper that are cited by several papers that are already in my bibliography, or papers which cite several entries I provided. If I find something interesting, I could "swipe right" (if you get my Tinder analogy) and that paper is added to my bibliography. The more paper I have in the bibliography, the more fitting the suggestions of the tool become. Of course such a tool should rely on an existing database (Scopus, google scholar, etc.)
Do you know anything like that?

Comment: The "tool" you want is probably just SQL or a specialized front end for it.

Comment: Qiqqa does this, no?

Comment: Mendeley also does this, although after I added some interesting papers it found, thereafter it unfortunately insisted on showing me the same three papers I had already looked at and deemed unrelated to my research over and over again...

Comment: I don't think this falls under "shopping question". It certainly isn't any of the examples mentioned in the canned close-reason ("recommendations or lists of individual universities, academic programs, publishers, journals, research topics, or similar)". We have a number of similar requests that are on-topic: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3655/is-there-any-referencing-style-analyzer https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38264/is-there-a-master-list-of-journals https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56679/is-there-an-archive-like-arxiv-org-for-agricultural-papers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as Mendeley, for Biology and Medicine people there is also [PubChase](https://www.pubchase.com/), which does exactly what you say you are looking for. How well it works I couldn't say. It always has interesting suggests for me, but I wouldn't rely on it to be comprehensive.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, in Science Direct, I see 'other papers that might interest you'.

Also if you're reading a really good paper look for the papers they cite and the other papers that have cited that paper.

I find this is incredibly useful when doing a literature survey.

Best of luck with it!

Comment: The “look at the references they used” is spot on!

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't use it myself actively, what you describe seems to be included in the [social network aspects of Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/research-network/community). Mendeley is primarily a fantastic reference management software (very similar in functionality to Zotero, which is what I personally use), but it additionally has a rich social component which seems to include recommendations of similar articles. So, it seems to both included the recommendation agent and reference storage features that you are looking for.

Another tool that partially has such features is [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net) (see the "Similar research" section when you scroll down below any article you look at). It has quite a rich recommendation agent, but not quite as rich reference storage features.